# Google Charts API labels with lines

Tags: javascript, html, charts

Is it possible to achieve the same effect with the 'new' Google Charts API like in the deprecated Image Charts service where the labels are outside the chart and a line points to the right pie slice?

Important: I know how to create the pie chart, I just don't know how I can achieve the: labels outside the chart + lines layout.

How it should look (uses deprecated Image Charts):

[image]

EDIT: just to make sure you guys don't write down to much code, I am just searching for the right properties to achieve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get a similar result by using the `legend.position` property and set its value to `labeled`.

Though the line points will be attached to the centers of the slices, it's not possible to reattach them to slice borders.

```
  var options = {
      legend: { position: 'labeled' }
  };

  // ...
  chart.draw(data, options);
```

The picture of the chart:
[image: Google pie chart with colored lines]

Comment: Did not thought this would have been a property of the legend, so I really looked over it. Thanks a lot!